# Special characters not being displayed properly inside text editors on a docker container

Tags: docker, centos7, vi, nano

I'm trying to display these Special Characters,`µß£¬`, on my Docker Container running java-centos' vi editor and nano editor, but the `ß` character is replaced with sort of a question mark `�` instead.

expected output: `µß£¬`
actual output: `µ�~_£¬`.

But I can echo these characters on the terminal?!?! So it's just to do with the editors not being able to display the `ß` character.

I've tried all the suggestions from changing the default locale from `POSIX` to `C.UTF-8` to setting the locale to German, to no avail.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nimmis/java-centos:oracle-8-jdk
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so I've got it to work by adding this line to the Dockerfile, it's to do with the locale not being set properly on Centos7.

`ENV LANG en_us.utf-8`

Comment: This works for me but I don't understand why it specificaly works with 'Lang' and not with 'LANG'.

Comment: @MarianoLEANCE it is a mistake. It worked for OP probably because the editor was coded rather loosely/leniently and is case-insensitive in reading environment variables, I've made an edit.